# How to stop javascript displaying an á instead of space character

Tags: javascript, html, utf

I can't get javascript to display a space character inside a dynamically created tag.
This is my latest attempt:

```
var myawesometag=document.createElement('span');
myawesometag.innerHTML='&#x00A0;';
current.appendChild(myawesometag);
```

The span tag shows but it displays a lowercase a acute(á).
I've tried innerHTML=innerHTML+' ',
also: `'&nbsp;'`, `'&#32;'`, '\u0020' and '&#x20';

Comment: Which encoding do you use? Show your encoding meta information. Do you have a `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`?

Comment: I have:

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I made this, which is the same code but it doesn't display the problem.
On my browser(chrome), instead of a space I get an á.

https://jsfiddle.net/woshLshf/

Comment: If it’s only on your browser, try setting the encoding to something else. Find that setting that causes this!

Comment: I've tried utf-8, 16, 32 and iso-8859-1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I found this:

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp

It seems I needed something called a figure space.

The following worked:

```
    var myawesometaghtml=myawesometag.innerHTML;
    myawesometaghtml=myawesometaghtml+'&#x2007;';
    myawesometag.innerHTML=myawesometaghtml;
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This is a different character than a non-breaking space. It does not answer the question why you had an acute being displayed.

Comment: Thanks trincot, I'll edit the question.
I'm sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The non-breaking space is `&nbsp;`, so the code should look like this:

```
myawesometag.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
```

Comment: [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op6j1nx8/) demonstrates that the OP's initial tag works (at least in some environments), and [This list of entities](http://www.chucke.com/entities.html) claims that OP's should be equivalent to `&nbsp`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this to the question, I shall amend it.
'&nbsp;' just shows the character 'á'.

Comment: @sanepete, Have you tried using these tags directly in HTML? Such as `<div>&nbsp;</div>`? I suspect the problem is not JavaScript-specific, but something related to the browser or the document meta tags.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding tags but no help.
I hope I've answered everyone's questions helpfully.

Comment: @sanepete It would probably help if you posted an entire HTML document, including the `DOCTYPE` and meta tags, for a page that exhibits this problem. The `body` tag can just include a single div with the `&nbsp;` and other entities you've tried.